# Get filename/PSChildName from within a Switch/Get-Content

Tags: powershell

I have the following code and I'm not sure how to access the filename from within the case block.

```
Switch -regex (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\ps-temp\*) {
  '\.DEBUG' {
     # How to access filename/PSChildName here?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can. `$_` is available inside the braces but it refers to the string being matched. Try `Select-String` cmdlet instead:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\ps-temp\* | Select-String '\.DEBUG'
```